# How can I execute query using job and convert result grid to text?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to execute query and convert result to text. I know how to do it within Management Studio. But I need to do it within stored procedure and saved output result to text column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query itself has no idea what a grid or text pane is - these are presentation niceties coded into Management Studio. If you want to combine the values in a row and concatenate them into a single string, then insert those rows into your text column (I hope you mean `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, since `TEXT` is deprecated and shouldn't be used), you can say something like this, keeping in mind that you'll need to manually convert any non-string types (`int`, `date`, etc.) to `varchar` or `nvarchar`.

```
INSERT dbo.OtherTable(NVARCHAR_MAX_COLUMN)
  SELECT varchar_column + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), int_column) + ...
  FROM dbo.table;
```

If you need to combine rows as well and insert one big value that represents a text dump of the whole table, then you can do it slightly differently:

```
DECLARE @v NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @v += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
    + varchar_column + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), int_column) + ...
    FROM dbo.table;

INSERT dbo.OtherTable(NVARCHAR_MAX_COLUMN) SELECT @v;
```